# How to use .defer with an internal data object d3 topoJSON map?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

After reading through all the documentation, I couldn't understand how to load an internal json object into a .defer for a d3 topoJSON map. My data object is passed to a front end JS file from a backend API call. Once on the front end it is in a data object that looks like the variable dataSet below:

```
var dataSet = [
{county: "021", county_name: "Franklin", county_TR_code: "53021", year: "2015", value: 7.5},
{county: "023", county_name: "Garfield", county_TR_code: "53023", year: "2015", value: 6.1},
{county: "025", county_name: "Grant", county_TR_code: "53025", year: "2015", value: 7.1},
{county: "027", county_name: "Grays Harbor", county_TR_code: "53027", year: "2015", value: 8.9},
{county: "029", county_name: "Island", county_TR_code: "53029", year: "2015", value: 6},
{county: "031", county_name: "Jefferson", county_TR_code: "53031", year: "2015", value: 7.1}]
```

I have been able to get just my topoJSON map of the counties in Washington to render, but I'm slightly confused as to how to set employmentData from my rawData variable. Any help would be great, thanks!

D3 Code below:

```
// Retrieve data from API
var rawData = dataSet

// Define funcitons to find min and max of data set
var minValue = getMin(rawData)
var maxValue = getMax(rawData)
var step = (maxValue-minValue)/7


// create color range based on Min,Max and Step Value
var employment_domain = [minValue,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
for(var i=1; i< employment_domain.length; i++){
  var tmp = (employment_domain[i-1] + step)
  employment_domain[i]= tmp
}
console.log('domain', employment_domain)

var employment_color = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain(employment_domain)
  .range(d3.schemeBlues[7])


var svg = d3.select("svg");
var path = d3.geoPath();

// Create variable to hold data 
// Dictionary of key value pairs {id: value} --> {censusBlockID: value}
var employmentData = d3.map();

// used to asynchronously load topojson maps and data
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "../maps/wa_counties.json") // load in topoJSON map data
  //
  .defer(rawData, function(d){
    console.log('d',d)
    employmentData.set(d.county_TR_code, +d.value) // (first refers to county code, second refers to employment value)
  } ) // load in data
  .await(ready) // create callback function

// Callback function
function ready(error, data){
  if (error) throw error;

  // if no error returned retrieve data from topojson file
  // used to refer to the features of the county data
  var county_data = topojson.feature(data, {
    type:"GeometryCollection",
    geometries: data.objects.tl_2016_53_tract.geometries
  });

  // identify projection and path
  var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
    .fitExtent([[20,20], [460, 580]], county_data) // assigns ([padding], [width and height], dataObject)

    // define path
    var geoPath = d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection)

    // draw map
    d3.select("svg.main_data_point").selectAll("path")
      .data(county_data.features) //pass in data
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", geoPath) // pass in geoPath object created
      .attr("fill", function(d){
        return employment_color(d.value = employmentData.get(d.properties.GEOID)); // pass in employement value and ID from topoJSON map
      }) // fill in the data


}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = d3.map();

yourinternaldata.forEach(function(d){
    console.log('d',d)
    data.set(d.code, +d.total) // (first refers to county code, second refers to employment value)
        })
```

use like this